# Ios Navigation bar spacing

Tags: layout, scrollview, ios10, ios11

I'm trying to place a scrollview such as the top of the view will be right below the navigation bar. I noticed that I have 2 different behavior on ios 10 and 11+.

On the image below, ios10 is on the right.
Here's a link to the code: https://github.com/floriel-fedry-cko/ios-scrollview.

Is there a way to fix it to have the same behavior on both?

[image: ios 10 and 11]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set Navigation Bar's translucent property to false. You can set it in code and storyboard both.

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
}
```